# Why does Scott Meyers recommend to prefer `iterator` to `const_iterator`

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

In item 26 of his book Effective STL, Scott Meyers recommends to prefer `iterator` over `const_iterator`. As I understand, he justifies this mainly by explaining that `const_iterator` does not work with certain functions like `insert` or `erase`.

But isn't that the whole point of a `const_iterator`, that it does not allow modifying the container? And maybe more importantly, it allows you to express this intention in your code.

Shouldn't he rather recommend to use `const_iterator` by default and only if you need to modify the container, use `iterator`?

Comment: How old is the book?  Not sure when cbegin and cend were introduced.

Comment: @Robinson: It's rather old, from 2001.

Comment: The dupe arrow should go the other way. The old question is explicitly off-topic by our current rules, since it's asking for an opinion, but there **is** an objective answer to this question.

Comment: Also, this belongs in an answer, not a comment, but the question is closed, so for now, here's a summary: (1) no, the whole point of `const_iterator` is that the *data* is `const`, not the container itself. `insert` and `erase` don't modify the *values* held by the container, so Meyers believes (or believed when he wrote *Effective STL*) that they should be permitted for use with `const_iterator`. (2) Meyers discusses this issue in the context of changes in C++11 that make `const_iterator` preferable. See *Effective Modern C++*, Item 13.

Comment: ...actually, C++11 *does* support [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) and [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) for `const_iterator`.

Comment: @kyle get answering.

Comment: `const_iterator` specifies that it will not modify the objects it points to - not that the container won't be modified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that Meyers *does* consider `const_iterator`s preferable when using an up-to-date implementation of the STL due to improvements made in the C++11 standard.

Before discussing his reasons for giving the anti-`const_iterator` advice in the first place and explaining what changed, though, I need to clear up a misconception. You write:

> isn't that the whole point of a `const_iterator`, that it does not allow modifying the container?

This is a sensible assumption, but in fact this is not quite the purpose of `const_iterator`. As Meyers explains in the third edition of *Effective C++* (written, notably, *before* C++11):

> Declaring an `iterator` `const` is like declaring a pointer `const` (i.e., declaring a `T* const` pointer): the `iterator` isn't allowed to point to something different, but the thing it points to may be modified. If you want an iterator that points to something that can't be modified (i.e., the STL analogue of a `const T*` pointer), you want a `const_iterator`[.]

In short, `const_iterator` doesn't protect against modifying the *container*, it protects against modifying the *contained values*. This is why Meyers expects `insert`to be compatible with `const_iterator`: it doesn't modify any of the elements already present in the container.

`erase` is a bit stranger, because it causes a contained element to be destroyed, which is a non-`const` operation. But note that the element's destructor is not called via the iterator itself; the iterator is merely the means the API provides to *specify* the item to be `erase`d. Semantically, a `const_iterator` should be able to serve this purpose as well as an an `iterator`.

---

Now, as for the advice in *Effective STL* and its subsequent retraction, I'll paraphrase and quote some of *Effective Modern C++* on the matter. In Item 13, "Prefer `const_iterator`s to `iterator`s", Meyers writes:

> ...in C++98, `const_iterators` had only halfhearted support. It wasn't that easy to create them, and once you had one, the ways you could use it were limited....
>
> ...there was no simple way to get a `const_iterator` from a non-`const` container...
>
> Once you had the `const_iterator`s...locations for insertions (and erasures) could be specified only by `iterator`s. `const_iterator`s weren't acceptable.

He gives an example making extensive use of `static_cast` to get around these limitations, but points out,

> ...the code I've shown might not compile, either, because there's no portable conversion from a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`, not even with a `static_cast`. Even the semantic sledgehammer known as `reinterpret_cast` can't do the job.

He summarizes:

> ...`const_iterator`s were so much trouble in C++98, they were rarely worth the bother.

These issues were addressed by the C++11 standard. As alluded to in a comment on your question, this standard introduced `cbegin` and `cend`, which return `const_iterator` regardless of whether the container itself is `const`. Also, [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) and [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) were given overloads taking `const_iterator`. This makes `const_iterator` much easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

The reasons he says in his book are:

> • Some versions of insert and erase require iterators. If you want to
>   call those functions, you're going to have to produce iterators.
>   const and reverse iterators won't do
>
> • It's not possible to implicitly convert a const iterator to an iterator,
>   and the technique described in Item 27 for generating an iterator
>   from a const_iterator is neither universally applicable nor guaranteed
>   to be efficient.

*But*, very important, he continues:

> Don't be fooled into thinking that this means const iterators are useless
>   in general. They're not. They're perfectly useful with algorithms,
>   because algorithms don't usually care what kind of iterators they
>   work with. as long as they are of the appropriate category. const iterators
>   are also acceptable for many container member functions. It's
>   only some forms of insert and erase that are picky.

So, as always, it strongly depends on the context and situation.

Comment: Yes, but I am wondering why he doesn't mention at all what I think is the main reason for the existence of `const_iterator` - to express that the iterator will not modify the container.

Comment: This answer is incomplete; any complete answer should refer to Meyers' argument in *Effective Modern C++* that "in C++98, `const_iterator`s had only halfhearted support".